# unwrap T from Nullable<T>

Tags: .net, nullable

Wanted a simple but efficient method to get value from Nullable when T is not known at the compile time.

So far have something like this:

```
public static object UnwrapNullable(object o)
{
    if (o == null)
        return null;

    if (o.GetType().IsGenericType && o.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>))
        return ???

    return o;
}
```

anything can be done here without dipping into dynamic code generation?

used on .NET 2.0

Comment: Do you that the object is a Nullable<T>, or do you not even know that much? If you know o is a Nullable<T>, then calling o.GetType() will return T.

Comment: Agree with dlev - why doesn't this function just take a Nullable<T>?

Comment: Why do you not know what T is at compile time?

Comment: Also, why unwrap `Nullable<T>` if you're just going to return `null`!?

Comment: @Tesserex, ICR: I'm guessing that this is done via reflections, hence he gets `object` back.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`o` can *never* refer to an instance of `Nullable<T>`. If you box a nullable value type value, you either end up with a boxed value of the *non-nullable* underlying type, or a null reference.

In other words, `o.GetType()` can *never* return `Nullable<T>` for *any* value of `o` - regardless of the type of `o`. For example:

```
Nullable<int> x = 10;
Console.WriteLine(x.GetType()); // System.Int32
```

Here we end up boxing the value of `x` because `GetType()` is declared on `object` and not overridden in `Nullable<T>` (because it's non-virtual). It's a little bit of an oddity.

Comment: hmmm yes I guess I didn't think that one through.

Answer (score 0):

It does not makes sense.

If you have code:

```
int? x = null; //int? == Nullable<int>
if ( null == x ) { Console.WriteLine("x is null"); }
else { Console.WriteLine( "x is " + x.ToString() ); }
```

The result will be "x is null" printed in console.